# Find cells with opposite duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to code something to find cells with same amount but opposite value.

A few additional rules:

- 1, all cells are in a column;
- 2, match aims to find pairs of values for example, (1 and -1, 2.0003 and - 2.0003, 31.3245678 and
  -31.3245678)--- if there are 3 of 1 and 4 of -1, only highlight 3 pairs of 1 and -1, leaving the extra -1 in the list without
  highlighting;
- 3, once a pair is highlighted, the pair is no longer considered in following match. that means, match continues for
  all remaining cells until all pairs in the column are found.

In the following picture, you can find a few pairs are highlighted, remaining cells are not matched, therefore remain in unfilled color.

[image: Example list]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use something like the following formula

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,-A:A)
```

To show how many negative duplicates a value has

[image]

---

To get only the first matching negatives use the following formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,-A:A)>=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1),TRUE,FALSE)
```

or even shorter

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,-A:A)>=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried this, It works well. but i want to have a code to highlight only the first pair that matches, if there is 1 2 and 100 -2, it only highlight first 2 and -2, leaving rest 99 -2 without any highlight. The reason i need this is because the list is huge, i cannot manually go through to pick out the first pair

Comment: @kuangli Please edit your original question and add a screenshot of an example data and what should be highlighted.

Comment: @Peh hi, description is edited, hope it makes sense this time :)

Comment: it is really clever to limit the number of match by the maximum of opposite value each have, so it only capture pairs :)